# How to measure standard compute load of a process

Tags: linux, performance, cpu-usage, benchmarking

I want to measure the CPU load of an application I am developing. I need to measure the CPU load in a processor and system neutral way. So, for example, if `top` shows the process uses 277% CPU at peak load, that metric is only meaningful on systems with identical CPU hardware. If we move the app to a system with faster or slower cores, or from Intel to AMD, then 277% won't mean anything.

It seems that units like IPS or FLOPS would be a good fit for this purpose. Those units are commonly used for comparing performance of different CPUs. It seems like they could also be used for helping users understand the CPU load requirements of an application up front.

Is there a tool for reporting the IPS and FLOPS used by a process?

ADDENDUM for clarity. For simplicity, imagine an app that processes "real-time data", whatever that means. A user will want to know the answer to this question: if the app is receiving X MBPS of real-time data, how many IPS or FLOPS will the app consume on my CPUs?

The point is to produce a system-independent metric of CPU usage by an application. A percentage doesn't help the user, unless their system is identical to the one where it was measured. It's no different than measuring the MPBS of network traffic, or storage IOPS, associated with an application. Users need this information to predict and plan how much hardware they must have to accommodate their workload.

Comment: "*Is there a tool for reporting the IPS and FLOPS used by a process?*" -- Your insight regarding system configuration affecting performance is correct, but your question is off the mark. IPS and FLOPS are metrics for hardware produced by benchmark SW (i.e. they are measurements of HW performance). Such metrics should not substantially change on a given system when the software is changed (unless there's custom optimizations for the HW).  A metric for software would probably involve measuring the elapsed time to complete a complex task/procedure rather than a fundamental rate.

Comment: "*I want to measure the CPU load of an application*" -- Why? You're probably asking an XY question. CPU load is a function of time, and not a static value as you report it.

Comment: @sawdust The whole point is that we want users to know how much CPU load the app will consume. So it's not about "a given system." It's about measuring IPS on system A, so that users with an entirely different system can reasonably anticipate how the app will perform on their system.

Comment: Also, the "why" is answer in the op: "If we move the app to a system with faster or slower cores, or from Intel to AMD". That is the why. Of course the value is not static and users would be interested in peak and average IPS/FLOPS metrics.